# Create saved search in NetSuite that displays which items have been ordered as a single line item

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

My goal is to see a list how many times an item has been ordered by itself and the quantity ordered.
so:

[image: Item]

Comment: I've done it before but it slips my mind at the moment. Can you try this first and see if the `DISTINCT` function works? `SUM(DISTINCT({linesequenceno}))`. What I'm after is counting the unique number of `{linesequenceno}`'s and as long as the sum is 1 then we know that is at least an order we are looking for. But, I need to make sure `DISTINCT` still works.

Comment: you can also checkout [this](http://www.netsuiterp.com/2019/06/saved-search-displaying-number-of-line.html)

Comment: @zerecees That answered my question. BUT you made me realize I asked the wrong question. I have edited my question. would you be kind enough to review it again?

Comment: No problem! It happens. I'm busy ATM but I will write back around 8 hours from now. We'll talk soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest method is a criteria where the line amount must equal the transaction total amount.

[image: Saved Search Criteria]
[image: Saved Search Results]

Comment: That's pretty clever. One problem is say I have an order where I sent something free? I am seeing those in my results.  Also, I added count on document number to show how many orders there were.

Comment: You can add a criteria: amount is greater than 0

Comment: Count of document number is the same as count of line sequence number in this case

Comment: Thanks on the amount greater than 0. That was a "duh" when I read it. sorry for asking a dumb question. I'm testing it now and it looks good so far.